# Lost Connection when trying to add new column to MYSQL table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to add a column to a mysql table that has over 25 million rows. I am running the sql command

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD COLUMN `column_name` varchar(128) NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

This is being run using the mysql command line application.

Every time i try to run this it takes hours and then i get the error

> ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query

The database is running in a RDS instance on AWS and checking the monitoring statistics neither the memory or disk space is being exhausted.

Is there anything else i can try to add this column to the table?

Answer (score 1):

The query may still be running.  With 25M records it's very possible that the query will take longer than your timeout.

Use `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` to check what is currently running on the server.  If your process is listed and the `State` is something like "`altering table`", it's just doing it's thing and taking a while.

Answer (score 0):

Check your memory usage or, more probably, your disk usage (is there enough free space during the process?). Altering a table may require either a large amount of memory or a copy on disk of your table. Changing the alter algorithm [from `INPLACE` to `COPY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-online-ddl-syntax.html) can be even faster in your particular case.

You may also be hitting the `innodb_online_alter_log_max_size` limit, although in that case, only the query should fail, not the entire server. It is possible that the crash may be happening due to the `ROLLBACK`, and not the operation itself, though.

Finally, some application configurations or hosting servers cancels a query/http request that is taking too long, I recommend you to execute the same query on the command line client for testing purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your speedy response however some of the points made are already covered in the question. 'Check your memory usage or your disk usage': As mentioned in the question the database is running on RDS and the monitoring shows there is plenty of memory and disk space. 'I recommend you to execute the same query on the command line client ': As stated in the question that is what i'm doing. The last thing you mentioned was changing the algorithm from INPLACE to COPY. However i am not happy about doing this as i have heard it could change my primary keys and lead to data integrity issues.