# MySQL, adding field to large table failure and space lost

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I am trying to add a field a big MySQL table:

```
mysql> alter table `offer_clicks` add `reconciled_at` datetime, algorithm=inplace, lock=none;
```

After some hours of work the process failed with:

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

I have tried this process several times each time with different errors, I have been solving one by one, the problem is that after the last error the disk space used in the process has not be recovered:

[image]

As you can see in the image above, I first upgraded the space of the disk because I knew adding the new field process was gonna consume around 700GB (I have tested it in another DB first), then I tried some times and after each failure the disk space was recovered, but not after the last failure.

#### Things I have tried:

- The process is not any more in the `show full processlist`.
- I have tried to **reboot** the instance (it is a RDS instance) but the file space still not recovered.
- The new field is not present in the table
- AWS developer forum thread: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=270830

How can I recover the lost space?

#### Update

Info about the table:

```
mysql> show table status where Name="offer_clicks" \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Name: offer_clicks
         Engine: InnoDB
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Dynamic
           Rows: 98238612
 Avg_row_length: 6102
    Data_length: 599495016448
Max_data_length: 0
   Index_length: 58622377984
      Data_free: 4194304
 Auto_increment: 145148580
    Create_time: 2017-06-30 10:40:11
    Update_time: 2017-12-30 10:28:49
     Check_time: NULL
      Collation: utf8_unicode_ci
       Checksum: NULL
 Create_options: 
        Comment: 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Important variables:

```
mysql> show variables where Variable_name="innodb_file_per_table" \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
Variable_name: innodb_file_per_table
        Value: ON
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Information about the temporary files:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.FILES WHERE TABLESPACE_NAME='innodb_temporary'\G   
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             FILE_ID: 775
           FILE_NAME: /rdsdbdata/db/innodb/ibtmp1
           FILE_TYPE: TEMPORARY
     TABLESPACE_NAME: innodb_temporary
       TABLE_CATALOG: 
        TABLE_SCHEMA: NULL
          TABLE_NAME: NULL
  LOGFILE_GROUP_NAME: NULL
LOGFILE_GROUP_NUMBER: NULL
              ENGINE: InnoDB
       FULLTEXT_KEYS: NULL
        DELETED_ROWS: NULL
        UPDATE_COUNT: NULL
        FREE_EXTENTS: 32
       TOTAL_EXTENTS: 76
         EXTENT_SIZE: 1048576
        INITIAL_SIZE: 12582912
        MAXIMUM_SIZE: NULL
     AUTOEXTEND_SIZE: 67108864
       CREATION_TIME: NULL
    LAST_UPDATE_TIME: NULL
    LAST_ACCESS_TIME: NULL
        RECOVER_TIME: NULL
 TRANSACTION_COUNTER: NULL
             VERSION: NULL
          ROW_FORMAT: NULL
          TABLE_ROWS: NULL
      AVG_ROW_LENGTH: NULL
         DATA_LENGTH: NULL
     MAX_DATA_LENGTH: NULL
        INDEX_LENGTH: NULL
           DATA_FREE: 75497472
         CREATE_TIME: NULL
         UPDATE_TIME: NULL
          CHECK_TIME: NULL
            CHECKSUM: NULL
              STATUS: NORMAL
               EXTRA: NULL
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Have you tried `optimize table` and have you checked your error logs? Also which engine are you using?

Comment: @nl-x I have added some table info to the question. I can't see the error log, they got deleted :/. About `optimize table` can I run it without degrading performance? this is a production Database.

Comment: Cant answer your question about degradation. I see you are using innodb, do you have innodb file per table in your my.cnf enabled?

Comment: Also, just wondering, did you check and see the process to add the column did really stop after the connection to your client was dropped? It could be the process is still running. `show full processlist`

Comment: Also, did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46807768/lost-connection-when-trying-to-add-new-column-to-mysql-table?rq=1 ?

Comment: @nl-x `innodb_file_per_table` is `ON`, the process is not there any more. Thanks of the link is what happened to me but I am not worry about the lost connection problem right now, but about the lost of space :/

Comment: Did you triple check the column hasn't been created? ;)

Comment: One more thing you can check. In the data folder of your database, can you see that the files for this table have grown hugely? Or do you have some files there indicating a temporary table, beginning with a #, which are very big. Their create date should be around the time you ran the query

Comment: Also read this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-temporary-tablespace.html

Comment: @nl-x the field is not there.. triple checked ;) (`ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'reconciled_at' in 'field list'`), even if the field were created a lot of space should be liberated after the process, I have checked this process in another database (replicated from a snapshot of the production one) and I have experienced this behaviour: after the field was crated the disk space was liberated.

Comment: @nl-x I have added some info in the question above about temporary files, I can not access to the file system because this is a RDS instance :/

Comment: @nl-x I have started the process `OPTIMIZE TABLE offer_clicks;`  not any performance degradation experienced but this process is also consuming disk :/ and I had to cancel it: https://imagebin.ca/v/3ma1VhQN1Ole

Comment: @nl-x I am following this doc to delete temporal tables: https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/get-rid-orphaned-innodb-temporary-tables-right-way but as I can not access to the file system I can not see the table names if any :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162246/discussion-between-fguillen-and-nl-x).